# How can i give the "free space" on my internal ssd to the APFS container, where macos is installed?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, ssd, apfs

I had Ubuntu installed in dual boot on my macbook pro 2018 with macOS Ventura 13.2.1 . Now I deleted the partition on which Linux was located and saw in Disk Utility that I don't have all of my SSD memory available.[image]

Using the diskutil list command, I get the following:

[image]

How can I reassign the "`free space`" to the container disk0s2?

I already tried this command: "`diskutil addpartition disk0s1 apfs NewAPFS 0`"  and got following:

> The new partition will be added following disk0s1 Started partitioning
> on disk0 Error: -69519: The target disk is too small for this
> operation, or a gap is required in your partition map which is missing
> or too small, which is often caused by an attempt to grow a partition
> beyond the beginning of another partition or beyond the end of
> partition map usable space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to first remove `disk0s3` by entering the command given below.

```
diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s3
```

Next, add all the free space to `disk0s2` by entering the command given below.

```
diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0
```